# Is it accaptable to say, “You're a cult and you’re going to hell”?

Tags: discussion

Are we allowed to call any group a cult and imply that they don’t have salvation, or that their faith isn’t good enough and they are going to hell?

Comment: You might find [In what different ways is the word "cult" used as a label inside Christianity?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/11532/30) useful in navigating the different ways "cult" gets used inside Christianity.

Comment: @Shog9 please help

Comment: @Caleb your version of hate speech isn't "correct".

Comment: Neither my comment nor the post I linked to says anything about hate speech.

Comment: Hate speech is, outside the law, speech that attacks a person or group on the basis of e.g. race, religion, gender, disability, or sexual orientation.

Comment: @caseyr547. @-mentions do not work for people who are not already participants in a conversation. (They work for post authors, post editors, and other commenter only.) In other words, you're not going to attract Shog9's attention by @-mentioning him here.

Comment: @TRiG yeah i was afraid of that and i dont have access to chat anymore...

Comment: @caseyr547 if you'd like to contact a community manager, please use the "contact us" page linked from the bottom of any page on the site. It sends an email to the community team.

Comment: @waxeagle i sent an email to shog i doubt he will respond i may go troll jon on bible hermanutics

Answer (score 7):

Throwing personal accusations around like "you're going to hell" is never an appropriate use of this site.

On the other hand the term "cult" does have [specific meanings](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/11532/30) that are relevant and the correct technical terminology for some contexts. In particular when answering from the perspective of a specific group, using the term in the way that they use in and identifying something as a cult in the way that they do may be appropriate.

As sensitive a topic as it is, some groups using the label "Christian" believe that some other groups have wrong beliefs that those wrong beliefs well end them up in hell. This is serious stuff and should be treated carefully. This site is not the place to work out who is ultimately right or wrong, but in the scope of some questions, these beliefs will come up and should be addressed frankly and in a way that is accurately representative of the groups that hold those views.

Is short:

- Personal name calling and diagnosis of other users spiritual state is off limits.
- Clinical, academic treatment of the views of various Christian groups is within the scope of this site even when it deals with such sensitive issues as various groups that believe others are wrong.